# Error in updating repository. no pub key

Tags: repository

[image]

```
krishna@ubuntu:~$ ls
    Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
krishna@ubuntu:~$ cd Desktop/
krishna@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ls
    key2.txt
krishna@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-key add key2.txt
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
krishna@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cd ..
krishna@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key EEA14886
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/krishna/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
krishna@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpg -a --export EEA14886 | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/krishna/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Comment: please [edit] your question, and explain what did you try to do? why should `key2.txt` be imported as key? what is the content of this file? etc

Comment: yes. i have to install haddop in ubuntu . so that prerquisites java and all i am installing but i m geeting error as no pub key thrown so i tried adding it as above. after adding key manually its showing above message as gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.. please help from last one week i am struggling

Comment: please [edit] your question, and make sure that you answer all points in my comment above (e.g. why should key2.txt be imported as key? what is the content of this file? )

Comment: content of key2.txt is ---EEA14886 value  because gpg error is saying nopubkey of EEA14886  cant be retrieved

Answer (score 0):

You should not run gpg as root. So try without sudo

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key EEA14886

gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server pgpkeys.mit.edu

gpg: key EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported

gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found

gpg: Total number processed: 1

gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Adding key to apt-key:

```
gpg -a --export EEA14886 | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for arun: 
OK
```

Verifying key:

```
apt-key list

 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg

--------------------
pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012)     <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012)     <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key     <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/C31D4FBC 2017-06-02
uid                  arun. <arunshankarm666@gmail.com>

pub   1024R/EEA14886 2010-05-04
uid                  Launchpad VLC
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60053/discussion-on-answer-by-arun-error-in-updating-repository-no-pub-key).